# Unable to resolve module `react`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I cloned https://github.com/oblador/react-native-progress

On the example folder:

```
npm i

react-native run-ios
```

But i got a error,this is the error screenshoot link: [`Unable to resolve module react`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpGIl.png)

This is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  Animated,
  Easing,
  View,
  ViewPropTypes,
} from 'react-native';
```

Why can't my `react` module not be resolved but `react native` module can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example has error on building node dependencies inside `package.json` file

```
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.47.2",
    "react-native-progress": "file:../" // error
  },
```

to fix that

1. inside Example folder run `npm uninstall react-native-progress`
2. after uninstall run `npm install react-native-progress --save`

then run your example app normally

Comment: But why `https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker/blob/develop/Example/package.json ` can run successfully？

Comment: react-native-progress has dependencies so it will search in node_modules  but it will confuse node where is the node_modules folder react-native-image-picker has no dependencies so it will run smoothly